# Android RDP / Terminal Server client with custom screen size

Tags: android, remote-access

I am looking for a RDP/Terminal Server client with support for custom screen size, because I want to run an application on my server from a device.

The "official" Microsoft RDP Client for Android doesn't have this ability. I'm trying [Jump Desktop](http://jumpdesktop.com/) but I'd like to have some alternative.

Thanks in advance.